# How to use the word discipline

Tags: phrase-usage

If I wish to state that I wish to be discipline, which of these statements are correct?

- I wish to be discipline
- I wish to be disciplined

Comment: The first version is syntactically incorrect for *any* meaning. The second could validly mean either *I want to have [more] self-control* OR *I want someone to "discipline" me* (implying sexual deviancy/masochism).

Comment: @Fumble - This may be a stretch, but the first one could be used if the speaker wanted to be discipline _personified_. (That would be an unusual usage, though, to say the least.)

Comment: @J.R.: Yeah, that possibility did cross my mind. But I thought it was so unlikely we could reasonably ignore it in an ELL context. About as likely as [Tom Snout in *A Midsummer Night's Dream*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Snout) saying to the casting director of the "play within a play" ***I wish to be wall***. Plausible in that context, maybe, but "syntactically incorrect" anywhere else.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I was ready to "reasonably ignore" it, too, until you said, "The first version is syntactically incorrect for *any* meaning" [emphasis in original]. That simply isn't true, and the last thing learners need is native speakers telling them that something is _always_ wrong when it's merely just _usually_ not what they want, or _likely_ not what they are trying to say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The second could also refer to a desire to be subject to discipline in a more literal, non-sexual sense. People sometimes acknowledge the value of proper discipline. They say things like, "No, I was wrong, I feel guilty for what I did, and I deserve to be disciplined for it." Or as the Bible says, "We have all had human fathers who disciplined us and we respected them for it. ... No discipline seems pleasant at the time, but painful. Later on, however, it produces a harvest of righteousness and peace for those who have been trained by it."

Comment: I certainly do not wish to be discipline personified. But the second causes the reader to think I wish for an external entity to discipline me and that is not what I intended to convey. I wish to say that I will put an effort to be more diciplined

Comment: @Lordbalmon: The "double-entendre" pretty much disappears once you include a quantifier such as ***more** disciplined*.

Comment: @Lordbalmon - Perhaps you want to say: _I want to have more [**self-discipline**_](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+self+discipline).

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** you're likely thinking of option 2.

---

**Long answer:**
Unless you want to be the literal (or metaphorical, it seems) embodiment of 'discipline', whatever that would mean, then you want to go with the latter. To be disciplined can mean that you want to have rigorous control over yourself, having honed away any non-contoured facets of [yourself/a particular trait or skill/anything related to you that is not now tempered]. Additionally, you could be saying that you want someone to discipline you, which is more akin to saying that you want to be punished, which itself can range the gamut from the paternal-sense, where it's an act intended to teach a lesson, keep the discipline-ee on a certain course, and/or display repercussions for one's actions, and it goes all to the psycho-sexual aspect, where the 'discipline' is actually a vehicle for sexual gratification (think *Fifty Shade Of Gray*).
However, whatever the case you intend to use it in, again, unless you're referring to becoming the thing itself, then it you go with the action (-ed, verb-form, 'disciplined'), while the embodied is looking to be the thing (noun-form, 'discipline').